# PlotLabel does not display variables in order

Tags: plotting

[image]

I can successfully plot a function, but I also want to include the variables in the PlotLabel. Yet, the order of the variables is not right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need `<>` between each pair of strings (i.e, after `ToString[..]`).  Without it, you're multiplying the strings with `Times[]` and `Times[]` sorts its arguments into standard order. -- You might find `StringTemplate[]` helpful, but I tend to use `Row[{..}]` for what you're doing.  `StringTemplate[]` is newer and `Row` is a habit.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!